# Yodlee Get Transactions REST Call Returns Empty Body

Tags: rest, api, testing, transactions, yodlee

I am testing the [getTransactions REST API](https://developer.yodlee.com/apidocs/index.php#!/transactions/getTransactions).

I am getting back 200 status code but the body returned in the response is empty "{}" to be precise. I have 5 user test accounts and neither of these returns any transactions.

I have tried it with and without the `?container=bank` (or creditCard) but no data is comming back.

When I execute getAccounts I get back a couple of accounts for each test user.

Not sure what the problem is. Is it possible that the test accounts were set up without any transactions? Is that likely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the transactions API returns 30 days of transactions. Please validate whether the transactions falls under last 30 days range. If not, try providing the fromDate value and call the transaction API.

Comment: Thank you that was the problem. The transactions that are populated in the test accounts come with 2013 and 2014 dates.